# PowerBI R: Manipulating with two different tables in R inside PowerBI

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Wile using R inside PowerBI's data transformation window, I need to access columns from other table. But itsnt happening.
In the following Image, you can see that I have two datasets.

1. "main_table", and
2. comput_table

I know that 'dataset' holds the input data for the script. But is it possible to call or use both tables within one single script ?

[image]

This is what i tried to do inside the main_table :

```
library(tidyverse)
comput_table1 = comput_table
comput_table1
```

The following is the error i get:

```
Error: object 'comput_table' not found
Execution halted
```

The above code is just a sample. I have many operations to do based on these two tables. Kindly help me to identify how to access/call the other table in R in Power BI